# Cloned form cannot be submitted

Tags: jquery, submit, clone, forms

I have a table, where each row corresponds to a form.  While the markup is invalid (`<form>` tags come after `<tr>` immediately), submit buttons work as expected (ie. they submit their containing form).  So far, so good.

Now I prepare a new row to be appended to the table mentioned above.  It resides hidden in a separate table.  When the 'Add a year' button pressed, I clone the `tr` with the form and append it to the table.  But here comes the suprise: the newly created submit button does not submit.  (I tried the same without cloning, makes no difference.)

Here are the code snippets (included in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9j4fx/1/)):

### HTML

```html
<div id="min" style="display:none">2010</div>

<div id="div_newyr" style="display:none">
<table>
    <tr>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
        <td class="td_yr">
            <span></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="yr" value="" />
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub_close" value="Close" /></td>
</form>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<table>
<tbody id="tb_yrs">
    <tr>
<form action="" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
        <td class="td_yr last">
            <span>2010</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="yr" value="2010" />
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="sub_close" value="Close" /></td>
</form>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<tbody>    
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="but_newyr" value="Add a year" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

### JS

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#but_newyr').click(function() {
        var firstYear = parseInt($('div#min').html());
        firstYear--;
        newRow = $('#div_newyr').find('tr').clone(true);
        newRow.find('td.td_yr').children('span').html(firstYear).next('input').val(firstYear);

        $('#tb_yrs').append(newRow);
        $('div#min').html(firstYear);
    });
});

//added on a tip from a deleted answer
$(document).on('click', "input[type=submit]" ,function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

If I make the to-be-cloned form visible in order to check whether it works before cloning, I can submit that form.  So, the question is: what is the difference between the original and the appended/cloned form or submit button?

(Just a sidenote: the appended row begins in line with the second cell under Chrome - but I think it has nothing to do with the submit.)

Comment: Do you need to programmatically assign two distinct names or ids to the two forms?

Comment: I usually don't give name to my forms.  The exception is when my forms are numerous and/or execedingly long.

Comment: Well if the two forms don't have an id or a name, it might be hard for the DOM to distinguish them. I know that in some cases when there is one form on a page things like the enter key work for submit, but if there are two this becomes disabled, could be something along those lines. My first suggestion would be to try giving them distinct names and ids.

Comment: Please check the newest version: http://jsfiddle.net/9j4fx/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('form').submit();
```

instead of

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

but better would be to avoid invalid markup, and either:

1. Don't use a table for layout
2. Don't use `form` elements - use jQuery to [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and submit the rows on demand